# Elasticsearch - match not_analyzed field with partial search term

Tags: performance, search, elasticsearch

I have a `"name" field - not_analyzed` in my elasticsearch index.

Lets say value of `"name" field` is `"some name"`. My question is, if I want a match for the search term - `some name some_more_name someother name` because it contains `some name` in it, then will `not_analyzed` allow that match to happen, if not, then how can I get a match for the proposed search term?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During the indexing the text of `name` field is stored in inverted index. If this field was analyzed, 2 terms would go to the inverted index: `some` and `name`. But as it is not analyzed, only 1 term is stored: `some name`
During the search (using match query), by default your search query is analyzed and tokenized. So there will be several terms: `some`, `name`, `some_more_name` and `someother`. Then Elasticsearch will look at inverted index to see if there is at least one term from the search query. But there is only `some name` term, so you won't see this document in the result set.
You can play with analyzers using [_analyze](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) endpoint

Returning to your question, if you want to get a match for the proposed search query, your field must be analyzed.

If you need to keep non-analyzed version as well you should use [multi fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html):

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "fields": {
            "analyzed": { 
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taras has explained  clearly,and i issue might have resolved,but still if you cant change mapping  of your index ,you can use query(I have tested in 5.4 ES)

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "namekey",
      "query": "*some* *name*",
      "default_operator": "OR"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Using wildcards always affect performance, specially if `some name` is actually `some1 some2 some3 some4 name1 name2 name3 name4`, related - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/exact-match-in-a-not-analyzed-field/37121